# Openui5 selectDialog throws unhandled error when bound to an odata.v4 model

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to use a OpenUI5 1.48.5 SelectDialog bound to an odata.v4 model.

The dialog displays correctly, however on item select the selectDialog fires a fireConfirmAndUpdateSelection event.

This gets handled by the Listbase, which requests the bindingContext from the ODataModel.v4 ... which is not supported on odata.v4 model so it throws an error!

How can I workaround this problem? Can I suppress the selectDialog firing this event? I realise i would then have to find the selected item myself.

Anyone seen similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: It was an issue in V1.48.5 of OpenUI5, but has been fixed in the latest master